# Need some help on the XRandR --fb command

Tags: display, xrandr, display-resolution

Recently I've been playing around with `xrandr` looking through `man` etc., so that I can finally find a way of getting `randr` to work on all systems - without getting `Gamma Failed`, `BadName` and `BadMatch` errors.

And I found the command `xrandr --fb widthxheight` - which `man` describes as:

> Reconfigures the screen to the specified size. All configured monitors must fit within this size. When this option is not provided, xrandr computes the smallest screen size that will hold the set of configured outputs; this option provides a way to override that behaviour.

I have a 1280x1024 monitor; when I use this command for a resolution lower than this, nothing happens. If a select a higher resolution, I still have 1280x1024 resolution but if I move the mouse to the side of the screen the visible elements onscreen are moved either up or to the left (not really sure how to explain this).

**Basically:** Why is this happening?

Comment: Not same effect for me,  you seem to have like panning? Using Ubuntu 15.10, `i915` driver, smaller buffer than resolution the screen results a  cut, I see only size of buffer & pointer is limited to that size. black or scrambled colors in the right and bottom bands. Larger frame buffer than resolution has no effect  only little bit extra memory for xorg. playing many times with framebuffer size, then i got an xorg crash :D, may be 32000x32000 was slap on the face.

Comment: Well, I'm lucky to get another machine to test, Ubuntu u14.04, `nvidia`  GT218M. Same as yours, lower got nothing, higher got panning to the right & bottom , black or tearing window edge in that extra band. However if I move a portion of a window there, it is well drawn and got refresh. Now I'm not sure, from driver or xorg/xrandr. I've to try same release, using live usb.

Comment: @Sneetsher thanks for all the help! I saw your answers yesterday, upvoted a couple, but will read through them properly today. I might not be able to accept all of them, since I want to keep some of the questions open in case others might find out other stuff. Thanks again **=)**

Comment: No problem DevRobot, I'm new to this topic and just started reading about `xrandr` the few day ago after I notice many question around here stayed unanswered and most without even an up vote. So there is a lack of interest or not enough collected info. :) you have couple of serialized related Qs, those help me tracking same path. :D I'm trying to figure out the missing ring.